# Azure IoT Edge - How to diagnose locally while offline?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

We are trying to create a simple local UI (standalone desktop app running on the Windows 10 Edge box) for displaying the overall health and diagnostics metrics on our IoT Edge device. The UI must be viewable if/when the device has no connection to the internet (offline). We want to show a list of modules, their status, last connection time, etc.  All of this info is available in the Module Twins, but I don't see any way to access the module twins locally, while offline.  Is there no local/shadow copy of these twins, or any api to query each module for its reported properties?
We are particularly interested in the edgeHub and edgeAgent modules, as they contain info about all the other modules, but I don't see any API to query those modules, other than the shell commands, `iotedge list`, `iotedge logs edgeAgent`, etc.

The only solution seems to be to programatically execute those shell commands and scrape the resulting output from the StandardOutput.  Seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I wanted to access the module twins outside of the IoT Edge process and whilst offline, I would probably [mount a volume to the module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-access-host-storage-from-module) and save my reported properties in a JSON file. That way your local UI can access the files on the host machine. Of course, that does mean the module's twins are now in a readable unencrypted state on your host machine.

A more complex scenario would be to expose an HTTP endpoint on each module to access the last known values. You would need to specify a port to open on each module for this to work. You can open a port in the deployment json:

```
"createOptions": {
    "ExposedPorts": {
        "80/tcp": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: These are both good, creative solutions.  Thank you.  I'm familiar with mounting volumes to modules, we do that for some of our modules.  And the web api could work too, however both require custom code added to each module, and thus would not work for edgeHub or edgeAgent.  I will likely just run the shell commands.  Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Glad I could help! Scraping the commands was one I would have never thought of, so thanks for the question!

Answer (score 2):

Also, consider leveraging the new built-in metrics from system modules coming in the 1.0.10 release. Here is a lab that will help you set this up end-to-end using release candidate bits:
https://labs.iotedge.dev/codelabs/monitor-iotedge